# Trying to refine several if statements down

Tags: c#, performance, if-statement, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to find a more elegant way to reduce my if statements down, what I have right now is a little messy and I reckon could be done better, any suggestions?

```
        if(ship.position.y >= transform.position.y + yBound)
        {
            hitBounds = true;
        }
        if(ship.position.y <= transform.position.y - yBound)
        {
            hitBounds = true;
        }
        if(ship.position.x >= transform.position.x + xBound)
        {
            hitBounds = true;
        }
        if(ship.position.x <= transform.position.x - xBound)
        {
            hitBounds = true;
        }
```

Thanks for your time!

**UPDATE**

```
if(Mathf.Abs(ship.position.x - transform.position.x) >= xBound || Mathf.Abs(ship.position.y - transform.position.y) >= yBound)
{
    hitBounds = true;
}
```

worked a treat, thanks a million!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
hitBounds = Math.Abs(ship.position.x - transform.position.x) >= xBound || Math.Abs(ship.position.y - transform.position.y) >= yBound;
```

Comment: Nice one. The only problem will happen if `hitBounds` is set by some other condition before that. As example, `hitBounds` is `true` before it, but condition is evaluated to `false`, then `hitBounds` becomes `false`, while it should remain `true`. OP didn't state if it is the case. If it is, then `hitBounds =` can be replaced with `hitBounds |=` or with `hitBounds = hitBounds || ...`.

Comment: hitBounds is only going to be set in this statement, couldn't use it without the if for some reason but will post the code I used now

Answer (score 0):

how about no if statement?

```
 hitBounds = (ship.position.y >= transform.position.y + yBound) || (ship.position.y <= transform.position.y - yBound) || (ship.position.x >= transform.position.x + xBound) || (ship.position.x <= transform.position.x - xBound);
```

Answer (score 0):

since in all conditions, hitBounds is "true".
You can use one if with || (OR) conditions.
I hope all these conditions are independent. If they are dependent use AND betwwen them.
Good luck!